# Z axis in Isometric tilemap

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, isometric

I'm experimenting with Isometric Tile Map's in JavaScript and HTML5 Canvas.
I'm storing Tile Map data in JavaScript 2D Array.

```
// 0 - Grass
// 1 - Dirt
// ...
var mapData = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    ...
]
```

and draw

```
for(var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < mapData[i].length; j++) {
        var p = iso2screen(i, j, 0); // X, Y, Z
        context.drawImage(tileArray[mapData[i][j]], p.x, p.y);
    }
}
```

but this function mean's all tile Z axis is equal to zero.

```
var p = iso2screen(i, j, 0);
```

Maybe anyone have idea and how to do something like `mapData[0][0]` Z axis equal to 3; `mapData[5][5]` Z axis equal to 5; ?

I'm have idea: Write function for Grass, Dirt and store this function to 2D Array and draw and later `mapData[0][0].setZ(3);`. But it is good idea to write functions for each tiles?

Comment: What is wrong with 3D map (3D array)?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer without knowing how Z affects the position of tile.
If Z simply means drawing order (and since HTML5 Canvas has no support for Z Index) then you should also store the tile data in a sorted array so that you can iterate over it while drawing single tiles.

For isometric tiles it is common that the uppermost tile (positioned at `(0,0)`) has a Z order of `(- mapWidth - mapHeight)` and any tile positioned at `(x,y)` has `( (-mapWidth + x) + (-mapHeight + y))`.

Also another concept of isometric tile maps are layers. A layer can be assigned a height property which shifts it above another layer.